# What are Paths in the git rm --cached Command?

Tags: git

The definition of `git rm --cached`:

> Use this option to unstage and remove **paths** only from the index.
> Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

What exactly are paths?

Answer (score 2):

A *path* is just a file name.  For instance:

- `README.md` is a file name, and also a path.  The path has no folder-like parts in it.
- `src/main.py` is a file name, and also a path.  The path has a folder-like part, `src`, and a file-like part, `main.py`, and your computer probably demands that Git actually create a folder/directory named `src` before Git can create a file named `main.py`.  To Git this is mostly just a file named `src/main.py`, but Git will accommodate your computer's quirk of demanding this weird separation of "files" and "folders", or whatever you like to call them.

Note that Git doesn't store folders.  Files are just files, in the index / staging-area, even if they have folder-ish parts in their names.  Git builds *new* commits from whatever is in the index at the time you run `git commit`,<sup>1</sup> so commits cannot store empty folders because the index cannot store a name that ends with a slash.<sup>2</sup>

The index itself, which is also called the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*, is a weird but crucial thing Git sticks in between the current commit and your *work-tree*.  Your work-tree is where you have your files, in their normal everyday form, that you can work with—but GIt doesn't use them to make new commits; Git uses the index.  So the index can be described, fairly accurately,<sup>3</sup> as your *proposed next commit*.  Running `git add` copies a file from your work-tree into the index.<sup>4</sup>  That makes the file ready to commit, unless of course you change it: then you have to copy it into the index again.

A file that exists in your work-tree is yours to do with as you will.  Git won't overwrite it except:

- when you check out a commit that has a file with that name (after making any folders needed to get to that point, as noted above), or
- when you are doing a `git merge` that requires putting Git's best effort at merging into the file, or
- when you specifically ask Git to overwrite it.

If the same path name, i.e., all the folder-y parts plus the final file name, is in the *index*, that work-tree file is *tracked*.  If not, the work-tree file is *untracked*.

Since Git makes the *next* commit from whatever is in the index, each *tracked* file goes into that next commit (in the form it has in the index, which is why you have to keep `git add`-ing it).  If the file *isn't* in the index, the next commit *won't* have that file.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you use `git commit -a` or some other forms of `git commit`, these effectively run `git add` for you just before actually committing.  But that's just a short-hand version of `git add <those files>; git commit`: Git still builds the commit from the index / staging-area.

<sup>2</sup>This is not strictly true.  Git *can* put such a path in the index.  But parts of Git keep insisting that this is a thing Git calls a *gitlink*, which is part of how Git keeps track of what Git calls *submodules*.  They therefore don't work right to hold empty folders / directories: these things turn into broken submodules, i.e., gitlinks without the right information to make the rest of it work.

<sup>3</sup>The index has some additional roles, especially during conflicted merges, that make this not entirely right.  But it's a reasonable mental model: you can think of the index as holding *copies* of all of the files that will go into the *next* commit.  They start out being copies of files from the *current* commit.  See also footnote 4.

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the index holds a *reference* to an internal Git *blob object*, rather than a copy of the file.  But this technical difference only really shows up if you start looking inside the index, with `git ls-files --stage` for instance, or start using `git update-index` to put object hash IDs into it.  If you just think of the index as holding a Git-ified copy of each file that will go into the next commit, that mental model works pretty well.

---

#### When `rm --cached` gets tricky

If we're in a normal everyday repository, we might add a totally new file:

```
$ git checkout -b feature master
<make all-new file>
$ git add newfile.ext
$ git commit
```

The new commit has a new file, that isn't in the old commit.  The new branch `feature` has the file in its tip commit, and `master` doesn't have the file.

Unsurprisingly, if we now:

```
$ git checkout master
```

the file `newfile.ext` vanishes from the work-tree.

More generally, suppose you move from a commit that *does* have the file to one that *doesn't*.  That is, you run `git checkout` for a commit (at the tip of some branch) that doesn't have file `newfile.ext` in it.  But `newfile.ext` is there now, in both your work-tree and in the index.  So Git has to pull the copy out of the index.  It also removes the copy from your work-tree.  That's what we just did, switching from `develop` (which has a new file) to `master` (which doesn't have the file).

Now let's go back to `develop`:

```
$ git checkout develop
```

The commit at the tip of `develop` *does* have file `newfile.ext`.  You don't have it in index or work-tree right now, so it's safe for Git to copy `newfile.ext` from the tip commit of `develop` into the index, and then copy that into your work-tree.  And now you *do* have the file, and life is good.

But: uh oh, we shouldn't have committed `newfile.ext` after all.  It's a configuration file, or a database of live users, or whatever.  We don't want it in `feature`.  So we remove it:

```
$ git rm newfile.ext
$ git commit
```

But, uh oh, we've lost our configuration (or database or whatever it was)!  So instead of `git rm`, let's not do the above two commands.  Instead, let's do:

```
$ git rm --cached newfile.ext
$ git commit
```

This time Git removes `newfile.ext` from the *index*, but not from our *work-tree*.  The *file* is still there in our work-tree.  It's gone from the index so it is not in the *new* commit on `feature`.

But now, if we check out the *old* commit on `feature`, e.g., by its hash ID, what happens?  Well, that commit *does* have `newfile.ext` in it.  Git wants to put that file into the index and copy it into the work-tree.

We'll usually get a complaint, that this `git checkout` would overwrite `newfile.ext`.  Sometimes—it's a little tricky exactly when—Git will overwrite `newfile.ext` anyway!  And if we force the checkout, Git will overwrite `newfile.ext` as we asked it to.  And now that file is in both the index, as seen in the commit where we saved it, and in regular (non-Git-ified) form in our work-tree.

Since it's in both index and work-tree, if we now `git checkout feature` or `git checkout master`—both of which identify commits that *don't* have the file—Git will now *remove* the file, from both index and work-tree.  Our precious config or database or whatever it is, is gone again!

So, know what `git rm --cached` does, but remember that it sets up these traps as well: commits in which the file *does* exist, and may overwrite something precious when you check them out.  You cannot change those existing commits: they will have that file forever.  The best you can do is avoid them, or stop using them altogether, if this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It means just that, the removed paths are removed from the index, but doesn't touch your working directory. This translates to, the files are removed from your staging area, but you will keep the files in your working directory. If you were to commit now, it will effectively remove those files from your repository.

Since your working directory is untouched, it will be as if you "added" those files again since they do not exist in the repository anymore. If you switched to a different branch or reset back to your head, you'll be returned to the state where the files are deleted and those files will be gone.

This could be useful if you're removing broken files with the intent to fix them. The repository will have them removed but you will still have the files where you can make the necessary changes.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thanks for your comment. Maybe I should be more specific about my question. What I was asking was what are exactly "paths" that git is referring to. Is path directory location inside which the removed file belongs? If so, does Git then track path of every file Git is tracking as well?

Comment: It could be files or directories that is currently in the repository at the currently checked out branch. Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :) If so, the removed file is no longer a part of repository, but still exists inside the working tree (or working directory). Because that is what I am seeing now (I assume when you say repository it means .git, not the directory inside which .git directory resides).

Comment: Correct. Though keep in mind, that it is removed when committed. But it will still exist in your commit history for your branch. So it will be there if you need to recover it.

Comment: Thank you again :) I was simply asking the definition of 'path' that the documentation refers to, not the mechanics of git rm --cached command. I now presume that 'path' is file or directory Git is tracking.